# Image Error in React-native

Tags: react-native

Why do I add the code in the red box will be submitted to the following error?
[image]
Error:

{"type":"InternalError","message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for details"}

Terminal Error:
[image]

Comment: you'd better show terminal error out

Comment: @CoderGLM This is my terminal error.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the icon is png;
2. If it is. Did you copied it from your native project, you'd better save it as png again.

I did encounter question as you stated, and I just saved my png icon as png again, and it works.